# Multiple composition of beans or beans as interface

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, mybatis, ibatis

In my company we have tables, beans for those tables, and SQL requests using those beans as output and those table as input (iBatis, myBatis, ..).

As usual, I create an entity bean for each table I use in an application.

But where a SQL request is using 7 tables, for example, I need to create a composition of 7 beans. And if another request is using 4 different table, I have to create another composition of 4 beans.

Now I'm wondering if I need to have as many compositions as multiple table tuples in requests the application has.

I thought about beans as interface to solve this problem but it doesn't seem to be possible.

**Example of the problem :**

Tables CUSTOMER, CAR, CUSTOMERCAR, RETAILER, CUSTOMERRETAILER, ...

SELECT customer.name, retailer.name, car.name WHERE ...

To handle this request output for those entities :

```
public CustomerRetailerCar {

    private Customer customer;
    private Car car;
    private Retailer retailer;

}
```

So I end up with a lot of compositions and I'm feeling I'm not solving this problem the right way. Am I wrong?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that association between entities is not expressed in your domain model (or at least is not used when mapping from database).

Namely if every `Customer` has a `Car` then there should be a field in `Customer` bean like:

```
private Car car
```

If `Customer` may have multiple cars the field should be a collection of `Car`s.

And the same for `Customer` <-> `Retailer` association.

In this case when you need to return customers with associated cars and retailers you don't need to create new class. The mapper should return existing `Customer` object with `car` and `retailer` fields set.

For examples how to map this in mybatis look to [examples in documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Advanced_Result_Maps)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but since most of our database table have more than 90 columns due to a bad normalization, our CTO doesn't want to add associations inside beans, like with Hibernate or JPA, but instead he wants us to fetch associations into separate entities by using only the resultClass output, not resultMap, so I'm having this problem about composition. I don't know how to solve it without reproducing the ugly database design that we cannot change.

Comment: Even if data is denormalized in db you still can map it to a correct domain model. At some place in the code there will be nomalization (namely some piece of code that knows that data stored in different row actually represent the same thing). It may be in java code (and you have a class per query result type) or you can store that in mapping and return a tree of objects with associations expressed explicitly in domain model. My point is that you can create more entities and/or DTOs and not have 90 columns in domain model but have composites and/or associations.

Comment: So should I desemantize objects into only attributes and get rid of the bean pattern mapped on tables, or put all beans inside a single abstract class that I instantiate for each result request in controller classes? I don't understand the need to create more composition classes when I have already beans.

Comment: My suggestion to create composites is to deal with the problem (the large number of columns) that prevents from creating explicit associations. AFAIU you don't want to add associations because there are already 90 columns. The way to deal the 90-columns-problem is to structure entities so that entity does not have 90 'primitive' attributes but have subentities or DTOs. Instead of making objects very database like I propose to create domain model with associations expressed explicitly via references. I don't suggest to not use beans. I don't quite get what you mean by `single abstract class`.